# Jquery Datepicker - If else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

If the input letter is 'A' then show an option to select Today's date & if Input has 'B' then it should not show an option to select today's date.

**Basically I need an if-else condition to change minDate: 0, to minDate: 1,**

Here is the link [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/AnthonyDavid/pen/Popdqde)

```
var text = $('.zip-input').val();
       
if(text.toLowerCase().match(/^a|^A/)){
  $("#TstDiv").html("London").css('color','green').fadeIn(100);

 $('#datepicker').datepicker({

      minDate: 0,
      constrainInput: true,
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
var day = date.getDay();
return [day != 0,''];
}

});
  
    
}else{
$("#TstDiv").html("uk").css('color','green').fadeIn(100);

 $('#datepicker').datepicker({

      minDate: 2,
      constrainInput: true,
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
var day = date.getDay();
return [day != 0,''];
}
     }); 

}  
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to destroy the existing datepicker before updating the
   options: `$("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");`
2. Change the minDate from `2` to `1` in the `else` statement
3. You can also simplify it a bit more by only updating the datepicker if there is a change in the first letter of the input and use tertiary operators to set the dynamic values.

Working example:

```js
var isLondon;

$(".zip-input").on("input", function() {
    var text = $(".zip-input").val();
    var firstLetter = text[0].toLowerCase();
    var currentIsLondon = (firstLetter === "a");
    if (isLondon !== currentIsLondon) {
        isLondon = currentIsLondon;
        $("#TstDiv").html(isLondon ? "London" : "uk").css('color','green').fadeIn(100);
        $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            minDate: isLondon ? 0 : 1,
            constrainInput: true,
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var day = date.getDay();
                return [day != 0, ""];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<span id="TstDiv"></span>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" maxlength="8" class="zip-input"  placeholder="Enter pincode" />
<input id="datepicker" placeholder="Select Delivery Date dd/mm/yyyy">
```